# Strings and Pointer locations

Tags: c++, string, parsing, visual-c++

I'm working on a program that needs to sift through a HTML/XML trash ridden .txt file for a specific pattern that has a number at the end of it. This pattern should occur 10 times. The pattern is as follows:" `<p class="wx-temp"> 93.`" The 93 is a temperature reading and what I am trying to harvest in the end, however, I cannot find a way to isolate the 93 from the rest of the string since it will change with every day that the program will be ideally run. I've been trying to find a way to define an integer data type that cannot be constant, (i.e. I can't enter a 93 at the end of the string because it would defeat the purpose) and have it in a string or something similar that I can set to an X number of characters after the end of the pattern to start, or in other words, pointer position. Sorry for the rambling. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Didn't I answer [a very similar question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360905/getting-10-day-weather-temperature-forecasts-in-c) yesterday?  You should show a snippet of the markup that contains your number so that a reasonable answer can be given.

Comment: @paddy: You have to use backticks otherwise the angle brackets are not displayed.

Comment: You can try searching for it with [regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex).

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have loaded the entire file into a single string, which is not unreasonable.

```
string html;
//(Some code that reads into a big string)
```

Now you just need to look for that tag.

```
string delimiter( "<p class=\"wx-temp\">" );
vector<int> temperatures;

size_t pos = html.find_first_of(delimiter);
while( pos != string::npos ) 
{
    // Skip past the tag (to the temperature)
    pos += delimiter.size();
    if( pos >= html.size() ) break;

    // Extract it (C-style) and chuck it into the vector.
    int temperature = atoi( html.c_str() + pos );
    temperatures.push_back(temperature);

    // If you want to stop after the first 10:
    if( temperatures.size() == 10 ) break; 

    // Find the next tag
    pos = html.find_first_of(delimiter, pos);
}
```